# calling ruby method in rails controller raises error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods

I have a rails app and I'm trying to call the methods below from the controller, but I get this error:

```
undefined local variable or method "service" for #<EventsController:0x007fb6d27da1c8>` for this line: `api_method: service.freebusy.query
```

What's the problem here? Why can't the `get_busy_events` see the service var if it's defined above it?

> controller

```
include GoogleCalendarApi
.....
@user = current_user
@google = @user.socials.where(provider: "google_oauth2").first
unless @google.blank?
  @client = init_google_api_calendar_client(@google)
  @result = open_gcal_connection(get_busy_events, @client, @google)
```

> lib/google_api_calendar.rb

```
def init_google_api_calendar_client(google_account)
  #method only called if google_oauth2 social exists
  client = Google::APIClient.new
  client.authorization.access_token = google_account.token
  client.authorization.client_id = ENV['GOOGLE_API_KEY']
  client.authorization.client_secret = ENV['GOOGLE_API_SECRET']
  client.authorization.refresh_token = google_account.refresh_token
  return client
end

def open_gcal_connection(options, initialized_client, social_object)
  client = initialized_client
  old_token = client.authorization.access_token
  service = client.discovered_api('calendar', 'v3')
  result = client.execute(options) #after execution you may get new token

  # update token if the token that was sent back is expired
  new_token = client.authorization.access_token
  if old_token != new_token
    social_object.update_attribute(token: new_token)
  end
  return result
end

def get_busy_events
  result = open_gcal_connection(
    api_method: service.freebusy.query,
    body: JSON.dump({ timeMin: '2015-12-24T17:06:02.000Z',
                   timeMax: '2013-12-31T17:06:02.000Z',
                   items: social_object.email }),
    headers: {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})
  #handling results
end
```

Comment: When you call `service` it treats it as a method of `EventController` because it is not defined inside the method it is called from. Default rails behaviour is to treat that as a method. if you are calling the `service` that is declared in the `open_gcal_connection`, I suggest you declare it in the `get_busy_events` action

Comment: Side note: you might get some unepexpected behaviour since it looks like you are calling the `open_gcal_connection` as one of its(`open_gcal_connection`) arguments. I don't know if that is intentional or not, but it looks sketchy

Comment: I'm just trying to keep it DRY based on the answer in the comment here: http://warolv.net/blog/2013/11/16/working-with-google-calendar-v3/ . Just don't know how to do it yet.

Comment: Steve, how should I change the code? If I put service = client.discovered_api('calendar', 'v3') to the get_busy_events, then client won't be defined :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question(as I did in the comments):

To fix your method, you have to define the `service` variable in the action where you are calling it.

As for your posted link: if you look at the `get_busy_events` method there is a line where `service = client.discovered_api('calendar', 'v3')`

and it is fine, because it is in the method. The same goes for `client` that the `service` declaration depends on- you have to declare them inside the method where you use them.

You should follow the article and make the code as it is there so you would have:

```
def init_client
  client = Google::APIClient.new
  # Fill client with all needed data
  client.authorization.access_token = @token #token is taken from auth table
  client.authorization.client_id = @oauth2_key
  client.authorization.client_secret = @oauth2_secret
  client.authorization.refresh_token = @refresh_token
  return client
end
```

which you can use to define `client` variable in all your other actions and then use the `service` method:

```
def get_busy_times
  client = init_client
  service = client.discovered_api('calendar', 'v3')
  @result = client.execute(
    :api_method => service.freebusy.query,
    :body_object => { :timeMin => start_time, #example: DateTime.now - 1.month
                      :timeMax => end_time, #example: DateTime.now + 1.month
                      :items => items
                    },
    :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'}})
end
```

EDIT No2:

Since you have a controller, where client is initialized I suggest passing it down as an argument:

```
include GoogleCalendarApi
.....
@user = current_user
@google = @user.socials.where(provider: "google_oauth2").first
unless @google.blank?
  @client = init_google_api_calendar_client(@google)
  @result = open_gcal_connection(get_busy_events(@client), @client, @google)
```

and changing your `get_busy_events` method:

```
def get_busy_events(client)
  service = client.discovered_api('calendar', 'v3')
  result = open_gcal_connection(
    api_method: service.freebusy.query,
    body: JSON.dump({ timeMin: '2015-12-24T17:06:02.000Z',
                   timeMax: '2013-12-31T17:06:02.000Z',
                   items: social_object.email }),
    headers: {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})
  #handling results
end
```

Although this is a bit weird for me(nesting arguments like this) so you should look at refactoring this.

Comment: Kkulikovskis, I have the init_client method called in my controller @client = init_google_api_calendar_client(@google), which is then passed to the open_gcal_connection method as an argument. I'm totally confused could you provide the full code example with the controller as well? (I edited my code and showing my init_client method as well). Btw. I need to identify the user as well and the code example in the post doesn't deal with that.

Comment: @SzilardMagyar It does. That is what the `init_client` does. Just pass it the `@user` as an argument and tweak it so you include the `@google` verification that you have in the controller action

Comment: Thanks @KKulikovskis. I didn't know I could pass argument within argument. I will figure something out. This is not the cleanest solution for sure. I may keep some repetitions, it won't be DRY but at least won't look weird.